# Scope restrictions of expl3 variables

Tags: expl3

The L3 programming layer imposes a number of restrictions on assignments to variables which are considered to be "LaTeX3 Error"s, namely: i) a variable must have been declared first before it is assigned a value; ii) a variable can be declared as either "local" or "global", and a given variable cannot receive an assignment different from its declared scope; iii) declaring a variable has global effects which, combined with the previous restriction, means it is not possible to use a variable whose existence is only local.

The document below illustrates these L3 errors:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage[enable-debug]{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\debug_on:n { check-declarations , deprecation }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% A global assignment of a local variable is not allowed.
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_package_variable_tl
\tl_gset:Nn \l_package_variable_tl {global value}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% An assignment to a variable which was not previously declared is not
% allowed.
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn \l_package_undeclared_var_tl {value}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% The previous restriction, however, implies we cannot rely on variables which
% exist only locally, since the variable declaration is always global.
\ExplSyntaxOn
\group_begin:
\tl_new:N \l_package_declared_var_tl
\group_end:
\tl_if_exist:NTF \l_package_declared_var_tl
  { \iow_term:n { Var~exists~outside~the~group. } }
  { \iow_term:n { Var~does~not~exist~outside~the~group. } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

This is all thoroughly documented as well, so the MWE is just an illustration of how deviations from the restrictions are considered by `check-declarations`, namely "errors".

I know one can go around these restrictions one way or another, but in considering doing so I'm not sure if I should. Particularly, since "I'm not a programmer"™, I might be failing to understand why these restrictions exist in the first place. So that's really the question: what's the rationale behind them?

Are these technical restrictions? These are not TeX restrictions, as far as I know, but is there something peculiar in TeX which makes these kinds of assignments problematic? Are these kinds of assignments "conceptually" or "logically" "wrong" in themselves? Is this a deliberate restriction to "attempt to curb bad coding practices in the ecosystem in general"? In sum, what are the reasons for them to be in place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The origin of this restriction is explained in The TeXbook, pg. 301:

> [image]  The special case of “save size” capacity exceeded is one of the most troublesome errors to correct, especially if you run into the error only on long jobs.  TeX generally uses up two words of save
> size whenever it performs a non-global assignment to some quantity
> whose previous value was not assigned at the same level of grouping.
> When macros are written properly, there will rarely be a need for more than 100 or~so things on the “save stack”; but it's possible to make save stack usage grow without limit if you make both local and global assignments to the same variable. You can figure out what TeX
> puts on the save stack by setting `\tracingrestores=1`; then your
> log file will record information about whatever is removed from the
> stack at the end of a group. For example, let `\a` stand for the
> command ‘`\advance\day by 1`’; let `\g` stand for ‘`\global\advance\day by 1`’; and consider the following commands:
>
> ```
> \day=1 {\a\g\a\g\a}
> ```
>
> The first `\a` sets `\day=2` and remembers the old value `\day=1` by putting it on the save stack. The first `\g` sets `\day=3`,  globally; nothing needs to go on the save stack at the time of a global assignment. The next `\a` sets `\day=4` and remembers the old value `\day=3` on the save stack. Then `\g` sets `\day=5`; then `\a` sets `\day=6` and remembers `\day=5`. Finally the ‘`}`’ causes TeX to go back through the save stack; if `\tracingrestores=1` at this point, the log file will get the following data:
>
> ```
> {restoring \day=5}
> {retaining \day=5}
> {retaining \day=5}
> ```
>
> Explanation: The `\day` parameter is first restored to its global value 5. Since this value is global, it will be retained, so the other saved values (`\day=3` and `\day=1`) are essentially ignored. Moral: If you find TeX retaining a lot of values, you have a set of macros that could cause the save stack to overflow in large enough jobs. To prevent this, it's usually wise to be consistent in your assignments to each variable that you use; the assignments should either be global always or local always.

When TeX is inside a grouping level, and you perform a local assignment, TeX will “save” the old value of the variable in the so-called “save stack” to restore it when the group ends.  But if you make a global assignment on top of it, it will “lock” the previous entry to the save stack then, when you do another local assignment to that variable, TeX will have to add yet another entry to the save stack.  Rinse and repeat, and you'll end up depleting that chunk of TeX's memory, and that's why Knuth recommends being consistent on the scope of assignments, and why `expl3` enforces that.

If you have precise control over the code you are writing, you can carefully mix global and local assignments to the same variable without running into trouble.  For example, there is no problem if you do a local assignment to a global variable inside a group (taking the example from The TeXbook, `\g{\a}\g`), or if you are on group level zero and do local assignments to a global variable.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137536/discussion-on-answer-by-phelype-oleinik-scope-restrictions-of-expl3-variables).